# For which values of x does the following series converge $ \sum_{0}^{\infty} (-1)^n/(\sqrt n+x^2) $?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I used the ratio test to solve for x but I am getting $ x^2 > -\sqrt n- \sqrt{n+1} $ and am therefore unable to solve for x. Is this a right method and are there alternative methods to solving this ?

Comment: you should use [Alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+x^2}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of positiv numbers (regardless of $x$). So by the convergence theorem of Leibniz$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n$ converges (regardless of $x$).